# Include RowId value in Nested Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rowid, nested-table

I have the below sample table:

```
create table data_test
(
    data_id     number,
    data_value  varchar2(100)
);
```

I want to use this as a nested table parameter in the below sample Stored Procedure by doing the below declaration:

```
create or replace package dat_pkg is

    type typ_dat_tst is table of data_test%rowtype index by pls_integer;

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst);

end dat_pkg;
/
```

I want `proc_test` to update the rows of data_test based on the `rowid` of the nested table:

```
create or replace package body dat_pkg is

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst)
    is
    begin

        for i in 1..p_dat.count loop

            update  data_test        
            set     data_value  = p_dat(i).data_value  
            where   data_id     = p_dat(i).data_id
            and     rowid       = p_dat(i).rowid;

        end loop;

    end proc_test;

end dat_pkg;
/
```

however i am getting the error `PLS-00302: component 'ROWID' must be declared` because its looking for the physical column rowid in the Nested Table.
The same error is being raised when i use the function `rowidtochar()`.

How can i include `rowid` as a physicial column in the Type declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ROWID` is a pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.htm), it isn't part of the data dictionary view of the table (e.g. it doesn't appear in `dba_tab_columns`), so it isn't included in the `%rowtype`. A PL/SQL record - which is what you are constructing a PL/SQL table of - has no physical storage, so no real or pseudo rowid.

If you really want to store the row ID in a record/table you would have to declare the type explicitly:

```
create or replace package dat_pkg is

    type typ_dat_rec is record (
        data_id     data_test.data_id%type,
        data_value  data_test.data_value%type,
        data_rowid  rowid);

    type typ_dat_tst is table of data_test%rowtype index by pls_integer;

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst);

end dat_pkg;
/
```

You can't call the record field just `rowid` as that is a data type, so I've prefixed it with `data_` but you might prefer something else. And then you need to use that field name in your package body, obviously:

```
create or replace package body dat_pkg is

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst)
    is
    begin

        for i in 1..p_dat.count loop

            update  data_test        
            set     data_value  = p_dat(i).data_value  
            where   data_id     = p_dat(i).data_id
            and     rowid       = p_dat(i).data_rowid;

        end loop;

    end proc_test;

end dat_pkg;
/
```

You could, as you suggested, store the entire row type *and* the row ID as two fields in the record type:

```
create or replace package dat_pkg is

    type typ_dat_rec is record (
        data_rec    data_test%rowtype,
        data_rowid  rowid);

    type typ_dat_tst is table of typ_dat_rec index by pls_integer;

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst);

end dat_pkg;
/
```

but that makes referring to the fields a bit more awkward:

```
...
        for i in 1..p_dat.count loop

            update  data_test        
            set     data_value  = p_dat(i).data_rec.data_value  
            where   data_id     = p_dat(i).data_rec.data_id
            and     rowid       = p_dat(i).data_rowid;

        end loop;
...
```

and it will probably make populating the collection more awkward too. As you have to know all the column/field names anyway to be able to refer to them in the loop, I'm not sure there's much advantage, but you may find it neater.

Of course, doing this at all assumes your collection is being populated from a subset of data from the table in the same DB and even session, since a row's  `rowid` can change over time. You might also want to look into the `forall` syntax to replace your `for` loop, depending on what you are really doing. (But you should also consider whether you need the collection at all - if you are just populating the collection and then using that for the update then a single SQL update would be faster still...)

Comment: would it be better if i defined it as below? 
    type typ_dat_rec is record (
        data_rec    data_test%rowtype,
        data_rowid  rowid);

Comment: I don't see that would really be better, but maybe depends how you're using it. It would work but you'd have another identifier when you use it, and it makes populating the collection more awkward.

Comment: Thanks for adding the suggestion, the reason i suggested using a `%rowtype` was because i have around 100 columns on that table and it would be somewhat "messy" for me to declare them in the type specification.

Comment: Yes, though if you need to refer to them all then you still need to know all their names, so listing them again isn't necessarily terrible using `%type` (and if you aren't referring to them all, only listing the ones you need will reduce memory usage a bit). Which is better is probably a matter of opinion here, and you choose where to have to do extra work.

Comment: is there a way to directly call the specific "column" `p_dat(i).data_value` using instead of `p_dat(i).data_rec.data_value`?

Comment: @MigsIsip - no, the record type has two field, one field is itself a record type with multiple fields. You need to specify each level.

Comment: In relation to this, can you help me out again? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009066/populate-an-associative-array-inside-a-nested-table