# Populate an Associative Array inside a Nested Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In relation to my Previous Question, [Include RowId value in Nested Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007623/include-rowid-value-in-nested-table),

I have the below sample table:

```
create table data_test
(
    data_id     number,
    data_value  varchar2(100),
    batch_name  varchar2(100)
);
```

I have used this table as a parameter which includes the rowid:

```
create or replace package dat_pkg is

    type typ_dat_rec is record (
        data_rec    data_test%rowtype,
        data_rowid  rowid);

    type typ_dat_tst is table of typ_dat_rec index by pls_integer;

    procedure transform_dat (p_batch_name data_test.batch_name%type);

    procedure proc_test (p_dat typ_dat_tst);

end dat_pkg;
/
```

Using the procedure `transform_dat`, I want to populate the variable `l_dat_rec` with the filtered records from the `data_test` table, transform the data, and finally update the records using the `proc_test` procedure:

```
create or replace package body dat_pkg is

    procedure transform_dat (p_batch_name data_test.batch_name%type)
    is

        cursor cur_dat is
        select rowid, a.*
        from   data_test a
        where  batch_name = p_batch_name;

        l_dat_rec typ_dat_tst;

    begin

        open    cur_dat;
        fetch   cur_dat
        BULK COLLECT
        into    l_dat_rec;
        close   cur_dat;

        -- Do the Transformation here. Example --            
        for i in l_dat_rec.count loop
            if l_dat_rec(i).data_value = 'hello' then
                l_dat_rec(i).data_id := l_dat_rec(i).data_id + l_dat_rec(i).data_id;
            else            
                l_dat_rec(i).data_id := l_dat_rec(i).data_id * l_dat_rec(i).data_id;
            end if;
        end loop;

        -- update the table            
        proc_test (p_dat => l_dat_rec);

    end transform_dat;

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst)
    is
    begin

        for i in 1..p_dat.count loop

            update  data_test        
            set     data_value  = p_dat(i).data_value  
            where   data_id     = p_dat(i).data_id
            and     rowid       = p_dat(i).data_rowid;

        end loop;

    end proc_test;

end dat_pkg;
/
```

however i am getting the error `PLS-00597: expression 'L_DAT_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type`. The same error is being raised when i use `BULK COLLECT`.

What should I use to populate `l_dat_rec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer to your previous question, I mentioned that populating the collection would be harder with the `%rowtype` field. As far as I'm aware, unless you declare an SQL-level object type instead of a record type you can't use `bulk collect` for this (though it's worth checking if that has changed in 12c perhaps).

I believe you are stuck with using a simpler cursor loop that builds the two fields in your type (i.e. the `%rowtype` sub-field and the `rowid` field) separately, and then builds up the collection a line at a time:

```
create or replace package body dat_pkg is

    procedure transform_dat (p_batch_name data_test.batch_name%type)
    is

        cursor cur_dat is
        select rowid, a.*
        from   data_test a
        where  batch_name = p_batch_name;

        l_dat_tst typ_dat_tst;
        l_rec data_test%rowtype;

    begin

        for rec_dat in cur_dat loop
            l_rec.data_id := rec_dat.data_id;
            l_rec.data_value := rec_dat.data_value;
            l_rec.batch_name := rec_dat.batch_name;
            -- or use a counter you increment for this...
            l_dat_tst(l_dat_tst.count + 1).data_rec := l_rec;
            l_dat_tst(l_dat_tst.count).data_rowid := rec_dat.rowid;
        end loop;

        -- Do the Transformation here. Example --            

        for i in 1..l_dat_tst.count loop
            if l_dat_tst(i).data_rec.data_value = 'hello' then
                l_dat_tst(i).data_rec.data_value := 'was hello';
            else            
                l_dat_tst(i).data_rec.data_value := 'was not hello';
            end if;
        end loop;

        -- update the table            
        proc_test (p_dat => l_dat_tst);

    end transform_dat;

    procedure proc_test (p_dat  typ_dat_tst)
    is
    begin

        for i in 1..p_dat.count loop

            update  data_test        
            set     data_value  = p_dat(i).data_rec.data_value  
            where   data_id     = p_dat(i).data_rec.data_id
            and     rowid       = p_dat(i).data_rowid;

        end loop;

    end proc_test;

end dat_pkg;
/
```

As also discussed before, the references to the sub-field-record's fields have to be qualified properly, so I've inserted `.data_rec` in the references in both procedures. I've changed the dummy transformation to modify the value instead of the ID, as that means no updates were ever going to happen.

Demo with some dummy data:

```
insert into data_test values (1, 'hello', 'test');
insert into data_test values (2, 'hello', 'test');
insert into data_test values (3, 'hello', 'exclude');
insert into data_test values (4, 'goodbye', 'test');


exec dat_pkg.transform_dat('test');

select * from data_test;

   DATA_ID DATA_VALUE           BATCH_NAME          
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 was hello            test                
         2 was hello            test                
         3 hello                exclude             
         4 was not hello        test
```